# Ordered logistic regression with likert scales

Tags: regression

I'm currently have a bit of difficulty determining how to analyze this data via logistic regression analysis.

- Q18 = DV (satisfaction score ranging from 1-10)
- Q10_1 = IV (Customer Service likert score from 1-5)
- Q10_2 = IV (Sales likert score from 1-5)
- Q10_3 = IV (Performance likert score from 1-5)
- Q10_4 = IV (price likert score from 1-5)
- Q10_5 = IV (proposal likret score from 1-5)
- Q10_6 = IV (collateral likert score from 1-5)
- Q10_7 = IV (reporting likert score from 1-5)
- Q10_8 = IV (manager likert score from 1-5)

My guess is that you need to use an ordered logistic regression model but i'm not sure what to factor in my formula just the DV or everything? Which equation is correct here?

> nps.olr <- polr(data = cs_aggmean, formula = factor(Q18) ~ Q10_1 + Q10_2 + Q10_3 + Q10_4 + Q10_5 + Q10_6 + Q10_7 + Q10_8)

or

> nps.olr <- polr(data = cs_aggmean, formula = factor(Q18) ~ factor(Q10_1) + factor(Q10_2) + factor(Q10_3) + factor(Q10_4) + factor(Q10_5) + factor(Q10_6) + factor(Q10_7) + factor(Q10_8))

After that I'm have trouble interpreting the results. For the first model the odds ratio I believe is this after I exponentiate the coefficients:

> exp(nps.olr$coefficients)
>   Q10_1 = 1.834354
>   Q10_2 = 1.354964
>   Q10_3 = 3.259454
>   Q10_4 = 1.269431
>   Q10_5 = 1.326062
>   Q10_6 = 1.432196
>   Q10_7 = 1.424732
>   Q10_8 = 1.010827

I appreciate any guidance here and of course just let me know if I need to supply more information!

Comment: This question might fare better on http://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: ah ok thanks for the tip!